# How can I have history completion / filtering when running R in Windows using the up/down arrows (like MATLAB)?

Tags: r, user-interface

I'm used to using R in Linux, which is wonderful. However, I really need to be using Windows. I've been using Rgui.exe that comes with the R installation and the history completion feature is missing. By this, I mean that I can start to type a command and then press the **up-arrow** to browse through the history for commands that start with what is typed (similar to the way MATLAB handles the history).

The closest thing I've found is to use RStudio, which allows this functionality with "Ctrl+Up Arrow" (which is a livable solution). It would be nice to be able to do this with just the arrow keys and to do it in Rgui.exe or other minimal R interface. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `Ctrl+Up Arrow` in RStudio. Brilliant.

Comment: isn't that functionality part of GNU readline? http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm

Comment: @richiemorrisroe your comment lead me to realize Rterm.exe actually includes this functionality. I was using Rgui.exe, which strangely doesn't. If you want to suggest using Rterm.exe as an answer, I will give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run R from [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), you can use reverse-i-search to cycle through commands that match the given pattern and which have been executed during the current R session.

Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> to initiate the reverse search, then as you type the pattern to be matched against the history, the most recently executed match will dynamically appear. Keep pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> to cycle through the matching items.

In the example depicted below, I've initiated a reverse search for 'LET'.

[image: reverse-i-search example]

Comment: It turns out it's unnecessary to run via Cygwin. This functionality is built in to Rterm, as indicated by @richiemorrisroe.

Comment: I'm making this the chosen answer, because Cygwin allows the cycling through (at least with the version I have now). If an answer appears that enables the use of up/down arrows to cycle through, I plan on accepting that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use RTerm.exe, as this includes tab completion (its very strange that RGUI on Windows doesn't, especially as the Mac GUI does).

Comment: RGui (2.14.1) on Windows does have tab completion, but it doesn't have what I'm calling (due to the lack of a better name) "history completion". Does the Mac GUI allow you to start to type something and then use the arrow keys to go through the commands in your history that begin with that?

Comment: This is interesting.. can you please describe how to use tab completion to cycle through the commands in the history that match the pattern? Sure, both the GUI and Rterm have tab completion for completing function names, but my interpretation of the question was that the OP wanted to be able to re-execute previously executed commands that matched the pattern.

Comment: @jbaums I believe that Alt +r should do the trick. I don't have access to a windows machine right now, so I can't really confirm this.

Comment: Apparently I was wrong about Rterm.exe having the up/down arrow functionality (which is what I was previously trying to convey). Strangely, it seems that Ctrl-R also doesn't cycle through the history if you press it multiple times in Rterm unless you open it up through cygwin.